# Finding an array elements location in a pandas frame column (a.k.a pd.series)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas, indexing

I have a pandas frame similar to this one:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Col1' : [4,5,6,7], 'Col2' : [10,20,30,40], 'Col3' : [100,50,-30,-50], 'Col4' : ['AAA', 'BBB', 'AAA', 'CCC']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index = ['R1','R2','R3','R4'])

    Col1  Col2  Col3 Col4
R1     4    10   100  AAA
R2     5    20    50  BBB
R3     6    30   -30  AAA
R4     7    40   -50  CCC
```

Given an array of targets:

```
target_array = np.array(['AAA', 'CCC', 'EEE'])
```

I would like to find the cell elements indices in `Col4` which also appear in the `target_array`.

I have tried to find a documented answer but it seems beyond my skill... Anyone has any advice?

P.S. Incidentally, for this particular case I can input a target array whose elements are the data frame indices names `array(['R1', 'R3', 'R5'])`. Would it be easier that way?

Edit 1:

Thank you very much for all the great replies. Sadly I can only choose one but everyone seems to point @Divakar as the best. Still you should look at piRSquared and MaxU speed comparisons for all the possibilities available

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`NumPy's in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) -

```
df.index[np.in1d(df['Col4'],target_array)]
```

**Explanation**

1) Create a `1D` mask corresponding to each row telling us whether there is a match between `col4's` element and any element in `target_array` :

```
mask = np.in1d(df['Col4'],target_array)
```

2) Use the mask to select valid indices from the dataframe as final output :

```
out = df.index[np.in1d(df['Col4'],target_array)]
```

Comment: @piRSquared Well I was hoping so, being a NumPy thing! ;)

Comment: @piRSquared That's what I have figured generally between NumPy and pandas, when talking about built-ins that do similar operations. But with groupby operations, I have seen pandas having an upper hand.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution and the explanation: It is nice to understand each step :)

Answer (score 11):

This should do it:

```
df.loc[df.Col4.isin(target_array)].index
```

---

EDIT:

I ran three options: from selected answers.  Mine, Bruce Pucci, and Divakar

[image]

Divakars was faster by a large amount.  I'd pick his.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comparison, it is very neat. Just one question: Do you think the data type (str) is affecting the speed differently on each method?

Comment: It changes things marginally.  But the order stays the same.

Comment: That is good to know. Thank you very much for the reply again

Answer (score 7):

For the sake of completeness I've added two (`.query()` variants) - my timings against 400K rows df:

```
In [63]: df.shape
Out[63]: (400000, 4)

In [64]:  %timeit df.index[np.in1d(df['Col4'],target_array)]
10 loops, best of 3: 35.1 ms per loop

In [65]: %timeit df.index[df.Col4.isin(target_array)]
10 loops, best of 3: 36.7 ms per loop

In [66]: %timeit df.loc[df.Col4.isin(target_array)].index
10 loops, best of 3: 47.8 ms per loop

In [67]: %timeit df.query('@target_array.tolist() == Col4')
10 loops, best of 3: 45.7 ms per loop

In [68]: %timeit df.query('@target_array in Col4')
10 loops, best of 3: 51.9 ms per loop
```

[Here is a similar comparison for (`not in ...`) and for different `dtypes`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38110564/5741205)

Comment: Thank you very much for the query options, it is a very nice discovery

Answer (score 5):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Col1' : [4,5,6,7], 'Col2' : [10,20,30,40], 'Col3' : [100,50,-30,-50], 'Col4' : ['AAA', 'BBB', 'AAA', 'CCC']}
target_array = np.array(['AAA', 'CCC', 'EEE'])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index = ['R1','R2','R3','R4'])

df['in_col'] = df['Col4'].apply(lambda x: x in target_array)
```

Is this what you were looking for?  Then you can groupby the new column and query the True elements.

Comment: Thank you very much for reminding my of the lambda: I am rather new to python and this is a very powerful/flexible tool

Answer (score 4):

```
df.index[df.Col4.isin(target_array)]
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply... it is a very neat approach since it uses only pandas functions