# Deleting DataFrame rows in Pandas based on column value - multiple values to remove

Tags: python, pandas, filter, dataframe

I have a list of values (not known in advance, in a Python list) that a column in my Panda DataFrame must not have for all rows.

All recipes on the Web (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172851/deleting-dataframe-row-in-pandas-based-on-column-value)) show how to do it with only one value to exclude, but I have multiple values to exclude. How do I do it?

Please note that I cannot hardcode the values to exclude in my code.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement 'in' and 'not in' for Pandas dataframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/how-to-implement-in-and-not-in-for-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do negative [isin()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-with-isin) indexing:

```
In [57]: df
Out[57]:
   a  b  c
0  1  2  2
1  1  7  0
2  3  7  1
3  3  2  7
4  1  3  1
5  3  4  2
6  0  7  1
7  5  4  3
8  6  1  0
9  3  2  0

In [58]: my_list = [1, 7, 8]

In [59]: df.loc[~df.b.isin(my_list)]
Out[59]:
   a  b  c
0  1  2  2
3  3  2  7
4  1  3  1
5  3  4  2
7  5  4  3
9  3  2  0
```

or using [query()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-in-and-not-in-operators) function:

```
In [60]: df.query('@my_list not in b')
Out[60]:
   a  b  c
0  1  2  2
3  3  2  7
4  1  3  1
5  3  4  2
7  5  4  3
9  3  2  0
```

Answer (score 4):

you could also use `np.in1d`.  From https://stackoverflow.com/a/38083418/2336654

For your use case:

```
df[~np.in1d(df.b, my_list)]
```

#### Demonstration

```
from string import ascii_letters, ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase
df = pd.DataFrame({'lower': list(ascii_lowercase), 'upper': list(ascii_uppercase)}).head(6)
exclude = list(ascii_uppercase[:6:2])

print df

  lower upper
0     a     A
1     b     B
2     c     C
3     d     D
4     e     E
5     f     F

print exclude

['A', 'C', 'E']

print df[~np.in1d(df.upper, exclude)]

  lower upper
1     b     B
3     d     D
5     f     F
```

---

#### Timing

Various methods

[image]

#### With 1.3 Million rows excluding 3 items

[image]

#### 1.3 Million rows excluding 12 items

[image]

#### Conclusion

Clearly, `isin` and `query` scale better in this case.

Comment: Pandas uses `np.in1d` [under the hood](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/05e734ab171be0fda838c6b12839c38fa588da2c/pandas/core/algorithms.py#L123).  It looks like they optimized it use `np.in1d` only when it will generally be beneficial, which is on large datasets.  It's slightly faster on your small example dataset, but when I tried it on similar data with 6k rows, and excluding 6 letters, `isin` was nearly twice as fast.

Comment: Also, I noticed that `ix` slows it down a bit.  I'll rerun over large dataset and excluding `ix`.

Comment: Yeah, it's still worthwhile to mention `np.in1d` regardless though, as it's often useful in other contexts too.

Comment: I just made [another comparison for different dtypes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38110564/5741205) - `np.in1d()` is __very__ slow for strings, but it wins for all numeric searches...

Answer (score 1):

I decided to add another answer with timings for different methods and different dtypes - it would be too long for one answer...

**Timings against 1M rows DF for the following dtypes: int32, int64, float64, object (string):**

[image]

```
In [207]: result
Out[207]:
                              int32  int64  float  string
method
df[~np.in1d(df.col, excl)]      249    271    307    2420
df[~df.col.isin(excl)]          414    210    514     189
df.ix[~df.col.isin(excl)]       399    212    553     189
df.query('@excl not in col')    415    228    563     206

In [208]: result.T
Out[208]:
method  df[~np.in1d(df.col, excl)]  df[~df.col.isin(excl)]  df.ix[~df.col.isin(excl)]  df.query('@excl not in col')
int32                          249                     414                        399                           415
int64                          271                     210                        212                           228
float                          307                     514                        553                           563
string                        2420                     189                        189                           206
```

**Raw results:**

**int32:**

```
In [159]: %timeit df[~np.in1d(df.int32, exclude_int32)]
1 loop, best of 3: 249 ms per loop

In [160]: %timeit df[~df.int32.isin(exclude_int32)]
1 loop, best of 3: 414 ms per loop

In [161]: %timeit df.ix[~df.int32.isin(exclude_int32)]
1 loop, best of 3: 399 ms per loop

In [162]: %timeit df.query('@exclude_int32 not in int32')
1 loop, best of 3: 415 ms per loop
```

**int64:**

```
In [163]: %timeit df[~np.in1d(df.int64, exclude_int64)]
1 loop, best of 3: 271 ms per loop

In [164]: %timeit df[~df.int64.isin(exclude_int64)]
1 loop, best of 3: 210 ms per loop

In [165]: %timeit df.ix[~df.int64.isin(exclude_int64)]
1 loop, best of 3: 212 ms per loop

In [166]: %timeit df.query('@exclude_int64 not in int64')
1 loop, best of 3: 228 ms per loop
```

**float64:**

```
In [167]: %timeit df[~np.in1d(df.float, exclude_float)]
1 loop, best of 3: 307 ms per loop

In [168]: %timeit df[~df.float.isin(exclude_float)]
1 loop, best of 3: 514 ms per loop

In [169]: %timeit df.ix[~df.float.isin(exclude_float)]
1 loop, best of 3: 553 ms per loop

In [170]: %timeit df.query('@exclude_float not in float')
1 loop, best of 3: 563 ms per loop
```

**object / string:**

```
In [171]: %timeit df[~np.in1d(df.string, exclude_str)]
1 loop, best of 3: 2.42 s per loop

In [172]: %timeit df[~df.string.isin(exclude_str)]
10 loops, best of 3: 189 ms per loop

In [173]: %timeit df.ix[~df.string.isin(exclude_str)]
10 loops, best of 3: 189 ms per loop

In [174]: %timeit df.query('@exclude_str not in string')
1 loop, best of 3: 206 ms per loop
```

**Conclusion:**

`np.in1d()` - wins for (`int32` and `float64`) searches, but it's **approx. 10 times** slower (compared to others) when searching strings, so don't use it for `object` (strings) and for `int64` dtypes!

**Setup:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'int32':    np.random.randint(0, 10**6, 10),
    'int64':    np.random.randint(10**7, 10**9, 10).astype(np.int64)*10,
    'float':    np.random.rand(10),
    'string':   np.random.choice([c*10 for c in string.ascii_uppercase], 10),
    })


df = pd.concat([df] * 10**5, ignore_index=True)

exclude_str = np.random.choice([c*10 for c in string.ascii_uppercase], 100).tolist()
exclude_int32 = np.random.randint(0, 10**6, 100).tolist()
exclude_int64 = (np.random.randint(10**7, 10**9, 100).astype(np.int64)*10).tolist()
exclude_float = np.random.rand(100)


In [146]: df.shape
Out[146]: (1000000, 4)

In [147]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1000000 entries, 0 to 999999
Data columns (total 4 columns):
float     1000000 non-null float64
int32     1000000 non-null int32
int64     1000000 non-null int64
string    1000000 non-null object
dtypes: float64(1), int32(1), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 26.7+ MB

In [148]: df.head()
Out[148]:
      float   int32       int64      string
0  0.221662  283447  6849265910  NNNNNNNNNN
1  0.276834  455464  8785039710  AAAAAAAAAA
2  0.517846  618887  8653293710  YYYYYYYYYY
3  0.318897  363191  2223601320  PPPPPPPPPP
4  0.323926  777875  5357201380  QQQQQQQQQQ
```