# python pandas filtering involving lists

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently using Pandas in python 2.7. My dataframe looks similar to this:

```
>>> df
        0
1  [1, 2]
2  [2, 3]
3  [4, 5]
```

Is it possible to filter rows by values *in* column 1? For example, if my filter value is 2, the filter should return a dataframe containing the first two rows.

I have tried a couple of ways already. The best thing I can think of is to do a list comprehension that returns the index of rows in which the value exist. Then, I could filter the dataframe with the list of indices. But, this would be very slow if I want to filter multiple times with different values. Ideally, I would like something that uses the build in Pandas functions in order to speed up the process.

Comment: You can use `np.in1d` as shown in the answer to : ['Finding an array elements location in a pandas frame column (a.k.a pd.series)'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38083227/finding-an-array-elements-location-in-a-pandas-frame-column-a-k-a-pd-series) for searching multiple values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'0':[[1, 2],[2, 3], [4, 5]]})
print (df)
        0
0  [1, 2]
1  [2, 3]
2  [4, 5]

print (df['0'].apply(lambda x: 2 in x))
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: 0, dtype: bool

print (df[df['0'].apply(lambda x: 2 in x)])
        0
0  [1, 2]
1  [2, 3]
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help. This works much faster than what I had. I was imagining there would be an answer that would look similar to df[2 in df[0]] though.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use boolean indexing with a list comprehension:

```
>>> df[[2 in row for row in df['0']]]
        0
0  [1, 2]
1  [2, 3]
```